# Требуется перевод сообщения на странице визиток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

Обнаружил ещё одно не переведённое сообщение в профиле участника.

---

> If you participate on multiple Stack Exchange sites, you can also show
>   off your combined profiles:

---

*Мой вариант перевода:*

> Если вы являетесь участником на нескольких сайтах Stack Exchange, то
>   также можете показать свои комбинированные профили:

---

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перевод слетел из-за замены явного указания адреса `http://stackexchange.com` на переменную `$url$`. Поэтому я решил оставить прежний вариант с учётом новой переменной:

> ```
> Если вы участвуете сразу в нескольких сообществах [Stack Exchange]($url$), вы можете похвастаться объединённой анкетой:
> ```

Будет на сайте после обновления Transifex и последующей сборки.